# Android: Scale layout to fit 7" Tablets like Nexus 7

Tags: android, scale, nexus-7, nexus-10

I have a landscape layout divided into two sections, the left section is the menu and the right section is the content.

I tested the application on

Nexus 10 which is an `xhdpi` device and Nexus 7 2013 which is also an `xhdpi` device

But the problem is that the menu will not fit entirely on the Nexus 7, only half the menu is displayed, is there anyway to scale the Menu so it fits devices like the Nexus 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, use the different folder for supporting different screen sizes to put a layout specific to a 7" tablet

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

you would want the folder `layout-sw600dp` to be specific

Comment: I understand that I need to create a new layout but the problem isn't with creating a new layout, in the left menu I have has 12 buttons vertically, each button is an Image (XHDPI) but since the Nexus 7 has a 7" screen instead of a 10" screen not all the contents of the Menu will be displayed only the first 7 options are dispalyed. Is there something I can do to make all the options scale down ?

Comment: use a scrollview? or change the size of the buttons in the different layout specific for the 7" tablet

Comment: it would probably be helpful if you showed us what it looked like

Comment: I'm already using a scrollview but since I have a background image for the entire menu and some things have to be in specific locations in the background it's not the behavior I want, I wish there was another way besides creating new images for 7" tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the android:weight=“1" attribute and set layout_width="wrap_ content" in the layout.XML

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @tyczj answer, also you should add `-land` suffix if you aim landscape orientation
e.g `layout-sw600dp-land`

Comment: I understand that I need to create a new layout but the problem isn't with creating a new layout, in the left menu I have has 12 buttons vertically, each button is an Image (XHDPI) but since the Nexus 7 has a 7" screen instead of a 10" screen not all the contents of the Menu will be displayed only the first 7 options are dispalyed. Is there something I can do to make all the options scale down ?

Comment: you can use 9-patch images, they will adjust theirselves, or if you past your layout xml i can better help

Answer (score 0):

You may have already gone over this, but I would suggest reading through, Android's guide on supporting 
multiple screen sizes. [Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)